# I want to remove this image

Tags: css

How can i remove this image:
[Image <--](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBQcH.png)

Link: [infinitefun20.blogspot.gr](http://infinitefun20.blogspot.gr)

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, provide a [mcve] and a clear problem statement. Please check the [help] and particularly [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you want to use **css**, just say with element has wich display property :
ypu can use browser inspect to see yor element has wich class name

```
.post-avatar {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the Image from blog will require to check the code where its coming out from. So better will be to use CSS and hide it.

use this:-

```
.post-avatar{
    display:none;
}
```